# rank and reduced row echelon form issue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I have following problem; I have given a matrix (1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9). it has to be equal (1,1,1)
I have done reduced row echelon form and ended up with following;
(1,2,3 | 1; 0,3,6 |3; 0,0,0 | 0)
so if x3=x3, then we may express 
x2=3-2x3 
x1=x3-5 
so if I set x3=0, I end up with x1=-5 and x2=3; however, if I replace these values to the original equation, I see erroneous result. Can someone explain to me what is my mistake/\

Comment: To be clear... you are asking for a vector $x$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$?  If so, you seem to be missing half of the most useful words in the question... for instance you don't mention $x$ at all until your attempt.

Comment: That said, if you were to have [row reduced the augmented matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B1%2C2%2C3%2C1%7D%2C%7B4%2C5%2C6%2C1%7D%2C%7B7%2C8%2C9%2C1%7D%7D) you would have arrived at finding $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ which is among the infinitely many described by Mohammad's answer below that [solves the question](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B4%2C5%2C6%7D%2C%7B7%2C8%2C9%7D%7D*%7B%7B-1%7D%2C%7B1%7D%2C%7B0%7D%7D).

Comment: thanks for ur answers still i don't know where i am making a mistake

Answer (score 0):

With $z=0$ you get $x=-1$ and $y=1$

Your system is dependent because the middle row is the average of the other two rows so you have infinitely many solutions.

For example you may assume $x=0$ and solve  for $y$ and $z$ to get $$ (x,y,z)= (0,-1,1)$$

You may let $x=t$ and solve for $y$ and $z$ in terms of $t$

My solution is $$(x,y,z)=(t,-2t-1,t+1)$$

Comment: thanks but I need my mistake